# Save output to new file every 10 seconds in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an output flow from COM-port and I want to save it to files, at that every 10 second new file.

I can read COM-port like this:

```
import sys
import datetime, threading


for line in sys.stdin:
    print(line)
    my_writing_function(line)
```

I need change filename every 10 seconds, so, probably I need something like this:

```
def filename():
    # if already opened -> close.
    filename='{0:%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S}'.format(datetime.datetime.now())
    fh = open(filename, "a+")   
    threading.Timer(10, filename).start()
```

But in this case fh should be global..
May be I need to make some flag and check it before writing?

Thanks.

Comment: If `fh` should be global then `global fh` will make it global. What's the reason  that you're not able to use `global`?

Comment: you could use a [TimedRotatingFileHandler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler) from logging

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
import logging
import time
import datetime
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def create_timed_rotating_log(path):
    logger = logging.getLogger("Rotating Log")
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(path, when="s", interval=2, backupCount=0)
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    while True:
        try:
            print('WHILE LOOP START')
            for line in sys.stdin:
                logger.info(line)
                # raise Exception
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')) + '\n' +str(e))

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    log_file = "log"
    create_timed_rotating_log(log_file)
```